# Problems with the consolekeys string C#

Tags: c#, string, console, char

I have a question about this code, which is simply supposed to write what I'm typing.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo a = Console.ReadKey();
if (a.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
{
     Console.Write(" ");
}
else if (a.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) 
{
     Console.WriteLine("");
}
else
{
     string b = a.Key.ToString();
     Console.Write(b);
}
```

If I'm clicking on d for example it prints:
`dD`

but if I check `b.Length` it equals 1. and if I try to `print b[0]` it is still printing `dD`. How is that possible? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ReadKey` method both reads a key and displays it to the user.  Hence when you hit "d" it displays "d", returns a `ConsoleKeyInfo` value and then your code displays "D".  This results in the "dD" display.

To stop this pass `true` to `ReadKey` to prevent the display

```
ConsoleInfo a = Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not printing `dD`, it is printing `D` which is the value of `a.Key.ToString()`. It is putting it immediately after `d` so in the console it looks like `dD`.

Comment: Well I had to put the code in a console app and run it before I figured it out :)